# Why does DOMXPath->evaluate() return false

Tags: php, validation, xpath, domxpath

I am trying to [`evaluate()`](http://php.net/manual/de/domxpath.evaluate.php) an input XPath by using the DOMXPath object and its evaluate() function. However, I am getting some unexpected results. In the example, the two XPath structures are more or less identical, with the exception of the `@begin` being compared in the invalid one. I do not understand why this code is invalid, though.

```
<?php

$newDomObj = new DOMDocument;
$newXpathObj = new DOMXPath($newDomObj);

$xpathValid = '//node[@cat="smain" and node[@rel="su" and @pt="vnw"] and node[@rel="hd" and @pt="ww"] and node[@rel="predc" and @cat="np" and node[@rel="det" and @pt="lid"] and node[@rel="hd" and @pt="n"]]]';
$xpathInvalid = '//node[@cat="smain" and node[@rel="su" and @pt="vnw" and number(@begin) < ../node[@rel="hd" and @pt="ww"]/number(@begin)] and node[@rel="hd" and @pt="ww" and number(@begin) < ../node[@rel="predc" and @cat="np"]/node[@rel="det" and @pt="lid"]/number(@begin)] and node[@rel="predc" and @cat="np" and node[@rel="det" and @pt="lid" and number(@begin) < ../node[@rel="hd" and @pt="n"]/number(@begin)] and node[@rel="hd" and @pt="n"]]]';

$valid = ($newXpathObj->evaluate($xpathValid) === false) ? false : true;
$invalid = ($newXpathObj->evaluate($xpathInvalid) === false) ? false : true;

var_dump($valid);
var_dump($invalid);
```

Output

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

(Note, to better inspect the given XPath structure you can use [my beautifier](http://bramvanroy.be/projects/xpath-beautifier/) -- disclaimer, I am the author of that tool. You can test the above PHP code [here](http://ideone.com/aVSX3G).)

So what is wrong about my XPath, or am I evaluating it in the wrong way? How can I evaluate this kind of XPath?

Comment: when i am running this one i am getting:- `Warning: DOMXPath::evaluate(): Invalid expression in ..........  on line 13` . But if i changed your  `$xpathValid  = 'count(row/entry[. = "en"])';`, then i get :- `float(0)`

Comment: @Anant Run it [here](http://ideone.com/aVSX3G).

Comment: here also warning is shown, BTW:- https://eval.in/653162 .

Comment: @Anant As you see, the warning basically says what I am asking. The XPath expression is not correct. But *why*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the following part of your 2nd XPath is not valid, since XPath 1.0 -which [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) supports- doesn't support calling function in a path step :

```
../node[@rel="hd" and @pt="n"]/number(@begin)]
```

If `../node[@rel="hd" and @pt="n"]` is guaranteed to always return at most 1 result, or if you only need to compare with the first item in case of multiple items are returned, then you can use the following expression instead :

```
number(../node[@rel="hd" and @pt="n"]/@begin)
```

Comment: Ah; that makes sense. From which version this kind of XPath is supported? 2.0?

Comment: @BramVanroy Yes, starting from 2.0. To verify, you can test the XPath in a tool that support both XPath 1.0 and above, such as [this](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath), or [this](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/)

Comment: Thank you. As the XPath is auto-generated and then edited by human interactors, I need to check its validity though. I'll keep looking for a method in PHP to validate XPath 2.0.